# I am a basic necessity for survival

Tags: riddle, english

> I am a basic necessity for survival
>   Drop survival's end and I'm a temple for meditation
>   Repeat temple's last to electrical
>   Replace electricity's first to sleep well at a friend's

*What on Earth could I be talking about?*

Comment: Be careful - these are definitely starting to smell like crappy mass-producible puzzles...

Comment: @rand al'thor Agreed. Which is why these 4 liners are done being produced for the next little bit.

Comment: @warspyking I don't want to be a [grumpy Gus](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Grumpy+Gus), but you ought to put forth more effort here. There's no theme, no rhyme, no intrigue... I'd hate to see an amusing type of word puzzle tarnished by an abundance of hastily written riddles.

Comment: @Roland You seem to think I don't think about these things before I post. I purposely make sure they don't rhyme.

Comment: @Roland http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20440/what-is-it-in-my-eyes-that-will-result-in-humanitys-demise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I am a basic necessity for survival*

> WATER.

*Drop survival's end and I'm a temple for meditation*

> WAT (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wat)).

*Repeat temple's last to electrical*

> WATT is a unit of (e.g. electrical) power.

*Replace electricity's first to sleep well at a friend's*

> BATT as in batting (wadding for a mattress) - thanks **Somo145**

warspy, you're making these too easy now! Also the watt is a unit of any sort of power, not just electrical.

Comment: Nice! You're almost there

Comment: I agree, it would be too easy, if that last answer really was "Matt". But no.

Comment: @warspyking Well, there aren't many words ending with "att"!

Comment: I'm sure you'll get it!

Comment: What about "batt" as in "batting" (wadding for a mattress)?

Comment: @warspyking batt? scatt? att?

Comment: Batt ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @warspyking Edited. (I didn't vote on the OP, btw.)

Comment: rand, I'm looking forward for quick solving skills: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20440/what-is-it-in-my-eyes-that-will-result-in-humanitys-demise